# Помогите написать стили

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать такую же поперечную линию в css без использования самой картинки. И как сделать кнопку меню так как на фотке на чистом html и css

Comment: Откуда взяли этот скрин?

Comment: PSD макет скачал

Answer (score 1):

Псевдоэлементы вам в помощь.
Кнопка делается аналогично. Устанавливаете блоку толщину 2px, для него же `:before` и `:after` также по 2px со смещением обоих. Далее вешаете на него обработчик по клику и меняете положение `:before` и `:after` на крест и раскрываете меню. А еще лучше прописать, скажем, класс `.active` в css и свойством `toggleClass` менять его.

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block:after {
  content: '';
  width: 140px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Только для кнопки ещё стоит прописать прозрачный бордер, что бы не было неактивных пустот между полосок, при нажатии на которые не происходит ожидаемого раскрытия меню.

Answer (score 1):

И без всяких фокусов.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, lightgreen calc(50% - 1px), white 50%, lightgreen 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Стоит поставить `lightgreen calc(50% + 1px)`, а то без этого пикселя линия какая-то драная: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HytfE.png, а с ним получается нормально: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H2GX.png

Comment: Или так. Принципиально роли не играет.